# Can storing return values in references perform worst?

Tags: c++, reference, return-value, auto

I am writing highly generic code, and I am handlying the return value from function calls as `const auto&`. So for example:

```
const auto& value = foo();
```

The purpose is to write it in the most generic way possible, so that it does not make any assumption on the return type of `foo`, which can return by value or return by reference without breaking anything on the client code even if the value is a temporary.

But can this code perform worst than:

```
const auto value = foo();
```

In case `foo()` is returning a basic type such as `int` or `double` or `enum`?

Comment: Unless the function returns something by reference itself, it doesn't make any sense in assigning it to a reference. And with the multiple possible return value optimizations (like [copy-elision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision)) and move semantics assigning to a "value" should not be that big a deal.

Comment: Very relevant, possibly a dupe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50106884/should-i-assign-a-ref-or-a-copy-to-a-value-returning-function

Comment: Also... maximum genericity is spelled `decltype(auto)`. Though that may depend on what you wish to make generic

Comment: Ultimately, I think the answer is "profile, profile, profile" of optimized code.  In addition to `const auto&` there is also `auto&&` and `decltype(auto)`... may need to become very familiar with their subtle differences.

Comment: @StoryTeller I did not ever though about `decltype(auto)`. I think it is what I need. What I want to make generic is the return type of the function that is called, as in my real code the function is a generic templated functor called with variadic templated args and so on.

Answer (score 8):

I understand why you may think it would incur a runtime cost, however, in practice this is not the case.

Any modern compiler will instantly fold this into the value type if the function returns a value type, instead of making it a reference. Your `const int&` would just become an `int` after compilation. You can test this out here: https://godbolt.org/g/vT2FdG.

Comment: ͏+͏1͏ Nice succinct answer; welcome to Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Galik The reference would only remain a reference if the original function returns a reference, which in this case, is what is wanted. However, if a value type is returned, then it will be optimized away.

Comment: @Galik Yes, I misunderstood your comment, please check my edit.

Comment: @Galik: AFAICT we are talking about the case where the function returns a value and is bound to a const reference, there's no other way to access/modify it.

Comment: @Galik If a reference is returned, then it will need to stay a reference because the value may be changed. However, if a value is returned, then the `const int&` becomes `int`. This was the potential slowdown the original poster was asking about, if a value type is returned.

Answer (score 2):

It depends.

In many cases, especially when `foo()` returns a primitive type, the reference will be optimized away and there will be no difference between both versions.

But if `foo()` returns a large-ish object, it can depend on whether NRVO is applicable or not.

The construct `auto value = foo();` enables NRVO, and `const auto& value = foo();` can sometimes prevent it ([demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b6c07e55e7fae7cf)). So the non-reference version can be faster.

But if NRVO isn't possible due to the way `foo()` is written, a temporary object may be created and copied. So the reference version will be faster.

Note: if the returned object isn't copy-constructible, then the non-reference version will fail to compile.

Comment: So basically there is no real why to make this code both highly generic, independent from whatever is being returned, and maximize performances at the same time...

Comment: @rustyx How does assigning to a `const T&` disable RVO? If the function returns plain `T`, the compiler can easily optimize it and use RVO. If the function returns `const T&`, RVO is impossible anyway because it needs to be a reference in case the value changes.

Comment: @JohnBoyer - Here's [an example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/709b0103c78231a0) to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: @rustyx You simply cannot demonstrate an issue regarding optimization with the flag `-O0`.

Comment: The result is the same with `-O3` as you can easily check.

Comment: @rustyx Why are two different functions being called? We are exclusively comparing `const auto x = func()` and `const auto& x = func()`. When you call the same function for `auto` and `auto&`, the same results are produced. Don't compare oranges with apples.

Comment: @JohnBoyer - I created that example to explain a bit of standartese on another question. I suggest you take the time to truly understand it before (quite arrogantly, btw) claiming it compares "apples and oranges". It clearly shows how favoring references can be a pessimization.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to *trial* the results for plain-old-data types, which includes inspecting the generated assembly on your target platforms.

For me, *instinct* suggests that

```
const int value = foo();
```

would be *faster* than

```
const int& value = foo();
```

since the overhead of setting up a reference - including the potential for lifetime extension - may be greater than a value copy of a plain-old-data type.

Where the cutoff is, if any, would be platform-dependent, and your optimising compiler might level the playing field in any case.

Answer (score 0):

Basing this on your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50798558/can-storing-return-values-in-references-perform-worst#comment88607083_50798558), the C++17 cookbook solution for working with generic functors that accept forwarded parameters is something like this:

1. If you need their return value, with value category and what not preserved, use a `decltype(auto)` variable to capture it.
2. Have your own functions's return type be `decltype(auto)`.
3. Use [`std::invoke`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke) to simplify the call site. And to truly support all sorts of curious functor types.
4. Use [`std::invoke_result`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/result_of) to handle the corner case where the return type is void. You don't want to be defining variables of type void.

All-in-all it makes for this template (of a template):

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <functional>
#include <utility>

template<class F, typename... Args>
decltype(auto) process_call(F&& f, Args&&... args) {
  if constexpr (std::is_void_v<std::invoke_result_t<F, Args...>>) {
    std::invoke(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    // Process without capturing 
    return;
  }
  else {
     decltype(auto) ret = std::invoke(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
     // Use ret for your processing
     return ret;
  }
}
```